# Will my Communities (Digital Experience) domain change to MyDomain when Enhanced Domains is activated?

Tags: lightning-community, custom-domain, mydomain, digital-experience

Sites were setup in our org long ago and our company name `CompanyX` is configured as one of the domains. It just so happens that `CompanyX` is also configured for `MyDomain`.

In the present, we are setting up a Communities (Digital Experience) site and want to use `CompanyX` as our Digital Experience domain but we can't. Salesforce tells us that `CompanyX` is not available, presumably because we are using it already via the Sites feature.

We have no other choice but to go with some variation of `CompanyX`, such as `CompanyXInc`. However, we also just learned about [Enhanced Domains](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000358662&type=1). It's our understanding that the `MyDomain` domain will be pushed out to all public facing features, including Sites and Digital Experiences.

So if we go with `CompanyXInc` today, when Enhanced Domains is released, will it automatically change our Digital Experience domain from `CompanyXInc` to `CompanyX`?

Also, will Salesforce redirect anyone visiting the Sites/Digital Experience community located at the old `CompanyXInc` path to the new `CompanyX` path?

Thank you.